# Error when passing in negative number into Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

newcomer to Haskell here.

I have this function:

```
addNums num1 num2 =
             num1 + num2
```

when I try to run `addNums 1 -2` with GHCi, it returns this error:

```
<interactive>:40:1: error:
* No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
    arising from a use of `print'
    (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
* In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I notice that in order for it to run as intended, I need to add parentheses: `addNums 1 (-2)`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

The code you wrote is being parsed as `(addNums 1) - 2`, so the compiler takes the result of `addNums 1`, which is a function `Integer -> Integer`, and tries to subtract `2` from it.

For correct passing order, you need to add parentheses around the second parameter:

```
addNum 1 (-2)
```

Comment: That's interesting.  Why doesn't it take in the second parameter if I have define the function to take in two parameters?

Comment: It does. Look at my final example. The function takes two parameters just fine.

Comment: I mean in the first paragraph, you said the code I wrote takes in (addNums 1) - 2.

Comment: Yes, that is how your code is parsed

Comment: Ok I believe I understand now. I was more so asking why exactly Haskell is parsing it like this. Is it because it see `-` as the infix operator which takes the highest precedence in this case?

Comment: @brainuser5705 Yes, infix `-` has lower precedence. The simplest thing to remember is: application `f x` has the highest precedence, so e.g. `f x+1` actually means `(f x) + 1`. (Also note that if `g` is a function with N arguments we can always pass fewer than N arguments and obtain a partially applied function. You won't get an error because of that, but you'll probably get a type error in the surrounding context which is not expecting a partially applied function.)

Comment: Enable `:set -XNegativeLiterals`. Then `addNums 1 -2` will be parsed as you expect: `addNums 1 (-2)`. It goes to show that GHC language extensions can be very simple.